# having same name in all text view when selecting image different images

Tags: android, image, android-intent, textview, implicit

I'm trying to set different name when selecting different images from gallary but pickup only one name and set there in all textviews..

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                imageName = selectedImageUri.getPath();

                if (mbinding.includeMainUploadIdcard.filenamePancard.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    mbinding.includeMainUploadIdcard.filenamePancard.setText(imageName);
                    mbinding.includeMainUploadIdcard.selectPancard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                if (mbinding.includeMainUploadIdcard.filenameAdharcard.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    mbinding.includeMainUploadIdcard.filenameAdharcard.setText(imageName);
                    mbinding.includeMainUploadIdcard.selectAdhar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }

                if (mbinding.includeMainUploadIdcard.filenameElectricityBill.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    mbinding.includeMainUploadIdcard.filenameElectricityBill.setText(imageName);
                    mbinding.includeMainUploadIdcard.selectBill.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
}
}
```

Comment: Wanna get image name from selected image?

Answer (score 0):

When you select a single image you get image path by data.getData().
And in the case of multiple images, you get all images paths by using data.clipData.

You can use the below code :

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {

            // For multiple images
            if(data.clipData!=null)
            {
               for(int i=0;i<data.clipData.ietmCount;i++){
                   imageUri=data.clipData.getItemAt(i).uri
                   }
            
            }else {
            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imageName = selectedImageUri.getPath();
            }

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this codes to display image and it's name from gallery :

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView imageView ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    
    /this code will let user to pick image from gallery
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    Intent.createChooser(intent,"title");
    startActivityForResult(intent,10);

}

// when we get back, the image we have selected will be here :
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // the image data
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        // the image Name
        String name = null;

        while (cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
            // here we get the name
            name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }

        // here to display image and it's name
        Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        imageView.setImageURI(uri);
    }
}

}
```

**activity_mail.xml**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**and for more details, visit : [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media)**